# Make ExtJS textarea expand with grow: true but only with click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I have a coding condition where I need to Have multiple ExtJS text areas. At the time of input I need them to be of certain size. i.e., grow: false.

Something like this:

```
me.outputDataPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    bodyStyle   : me.htmlBodyStyle,
    cls         : 'htmlView_font',
    border: 0,
    style: 'margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;'
});

   var textField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
    enforceMaxLength: true,
    maxLength: 5000,
    grow: false,
    fieldStyle: {
        'fontFamily': me.textFont,
        'fontSize': '16px'
    },
    style: 'padding-top: 10px ; padding-bottom: 30px;',
    width: '94%'
});
me.outputDataPanel.insert(me.itemIndex, textField);
me.itemIndex+=me.itemIndex;
```

Now I have a button on click of which each textbox should resize itself to show entire content in the box. i.e., dynamically make it grow: true. How can I achieve this?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`autoSize()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-method-autoSize) method.

> Automatically grows the field to accomodate the height of the text up
>   to the maximum field height allowed. This only takes effect if grow =
>   true, and fires the autosize event if the height changes.

Working Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/131r

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in this Fiddle. Am I doing something wrong? Could you please check? I am using ExtJS 4.2 in my application

Comment: What does not work? Have you added a few lines and pressed the button?

Comment: I don't know.. It didn't work in the Fiddle. In the Fiddle, on click of the grow Button, nothing seems to happen. I embedded the code in my application and it seems to work fine but only for small data set. If I put large text, after a certain height, scrollbars appear even after autosize.

Comment: Maybe that's because of `growMax`, read the documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-cfg-growMax

Comment: Is there a way to change the value of growMax ?

Comment: Try this for example: `textareaField.growMax = 200; textareaField.autoSize();`